# php update set all to 0, but for certain id to 1

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a form with checkboxes of all rows in my database.
The user is supposed to select the one he/she wants visible and submit that form.
So in the database I want to set all rows "visible" column to false but the one that is selected to true.
I thought this should work:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `questions` 
    SET `visible` = false;
    SET `visible` = true WHERE ID={$radio}" ;
```

but I can apparently not run multiple SETs like this. Also there isn't a if-else-like statement in php, right?

What would be a good way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [conditional statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html):

```
UPDATE `questions` 
SET `visible` = 
 CASE
   WHEN ID = '$radio' THEN true
   ELSE false
 END
```

Also, make sure to sanitize the user input before pasting it into a query.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it that way:

```
UPDATE `questions` 
SET `visible` = (ID = {$radio})
```

When `ID = $radio` equals to `true`, then `visible` is set to `true`, and `visible` is set to `false` in all other cases.